# Ignore error in SQL loader

Tags: oracle11g, sql-loader

I want to ignore last line from .csv file whose all fields are null. But while importing the data I don't want SQL loader to generate an error saying "Rows not loaded because all fields were null" or "Row not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed". I want it to import data without generating any error.

Is there any way to do that? I have tried Trailing Nullcols and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can know how many rows are in the file ahead of time you can use the LOAD= option to tell sqlldr how many rows to load. On the other hand, if you are doing pre-processing to figure that out then you could just remove the blank line, unless your spec is to not alter files.

Or just load all rows into a staging table and process from there, which is a common way to handle loading.

Comment: i can not alter csv file. they are directly coming from server. And the number of rows is way large so i can't count and do that either. I just need a way through which it will load all rows and ignore null row without giving an error

Comment: Either use a staging table or just accept that is how it is designed to work.  It's not really an error, even though it sounds like it :-/

Comment: @varad Wait, There's no reason you can't write a wrapper script that gets a line count of the file, then calls sqlldr using the option of LOAD=<the count minus 1>.  What OS are you using?  To get a line count on *nix, use `wc -l` or on windows use `find /c /v "" < filename.dat`.  You need to get a little creative here with your restrictions, that's all :-)

Comment: OPTIONS ( DIRECT=FALSE, SILENT=(FEEDBACK, DISCARDS) ,
 
SKIP=2 , ERRORs=9999999999)

LOAD DATA

INFILE 'PATH/FILE_NAME.csv'

TRUNCATE

INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","

optionally enclosed by '"'

TRAILING NULLCOLS

This is the part of the code. Can you tell where to add the word count line? @Gary_W

Comment: It says : 'wc-l-1' is not a legal integer for 'skip'

Comment: Well, you'd have to calculate it in the wrapper script, then put the output in a dynamically built command line that calls sqlldr.  Too much for continued discussion here in the comment section I'm afraid.  Scroll down to OPTIONS clause: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1009196

Comment: I think you'd be better off loading all rows into a staging table, then inserting from there via a PL/SQL program into your main table where you can select where not null and leave the blank row behind.  That way you could do more stringent data validation in the PL/SQL program as well.

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: You bet, let us know what you ended up doing.